# Looking for ONLY a hint on how to do this question

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

"Consider the polytope in $\mathbb{R}^4$ generated by taking the convex hull of the points $(\pm 1,0,0,0),(0,\pm 1,0,0),(0,0,\pm 1,0),$ and $(0,0,0,\pm 1)$. Describe all of its faces. How many are there in total?"

My issue is simply that I cannot see how you can do this (count the number of faces in 4-D) since I do not know how the vertices are connected.  For instance, is a vertex connect to $3$ other vertexes etc.

I am only looking for a hint here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @john Have you considered the corresponding problem in $\Bbb R^3$? Solving this problem should give you a good guess as to the answer for this problem. Note that in $\Bbb R^3$, some 2D faces are the convex hull of $3$ vertices and some are the convex hull of $4$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Technically, the polytope is one of its own "faces"; I'll refer to the rest of the faces as "proper" faces.

Each proper face corresponds to a set $S$ of vertices. Note that if the convex hull of $S$ intersects the interior of the polytope, then $S$ does not lie within a face. Note that if the affine subspace "spanned" by a subset is the same for sets $S_1,S_2$, then these subsets correspond to the same face.

With that said: consider pairs of vertices. Then consider subsets of $3$ non co-linear vertices. Then consider subsets of $4$ non co-planar vertices. Among these sets, which have a convex hull that intersects the interior? Which sets correspond to the same face?